# What profile does Selenium WebDriver use by default?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Where does Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a Selenium 2) get the anonymous profile that it uses when it opens FirefoxDriver? If it used the default for Firefox, %appdata%/roaming/mozilla/firefox/profiles, then if I were to disable a firefox plugin, it should be disabled for Selenium WebDriver also, so why isn't it?

Comment: AFAIK it's always a brand new one. You should just create your own and modify it to your needs.

Comment: ok its a brand new one, but it is still basing it on some prototype stored on a computer, since it is remembering to start up an addon that was since disabled within firefox. Where is this prototype?

Comment: I guess it's the one firefox provides, if you specify the `-CreateProfile` option on the command line. e.g. `firefox -CreateProfile test`. So what you are asking for is rather a firefox question, than a selenium one. I still recommend just to create a new Profile using the Profile Manager, e.g. `firefox.exe -ProfileManager`

Comment: In the headless case install / start something like `xvfb` (framebuffer server) and you will be able to use `DISPLAY=:11.0 firefox -CreateProfile test`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I will answer it, supporting comment from @twall: When starting firefox in Selenium 2 WebDriver, it starts new, anonymous profile.

However, if you want to change it, you can [create new Firefox profile](http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/) and name it somehow, you know what it is - e.g. `SELENIUM`

Then in your code do this:

```
 ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
 FirefoxProfile ffprofile = profile.getProfile("SELENIUM");
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
```

That way, Firefox will always start that profile. In the profile you do all the settings you need

Comment: What kind of code is this? I.e., I'm using selenium in Rails via the capybara and selenium-webdriver gems.

Comment: can i use this profile the way i used several user logins by using single browsers? @PavelJanicek

Answer (score 5):

You can assign to each Selenium grid 2 node a specific firefox profile:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar
>   **-Dwebdriver.firefox.profile**=my-profile  -role node -hub http://example-server.org:4444/grid/register

Notice that the value of the webdriver.firefox.profile has to be the **firefox profile name**, not the location or the folder name

Answer (score 2):

When running webdriver on a test server with no options to create profiles on the machine you can create your profile programmatically:

```
private FirefoxProfile GetFirefoxProfile()
{
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris", "http://localhost");
    return firefoxProfile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fetching a profile is not useful as it is internally creating another copy of the fetched named profile. Accessing the original profile is required if 
for eg: test coverage data should be written to a data store across multiple invocations.

Here is a possible solution by Overriding the ProfilesIni class of Selenium

Start by creating a Custom profile using firefox -p, say "CustomSeleniumProfile"

```
ProfilesIni profileini = new ProfilesIni() {
    @Override
    public FirefoxProfile getProfile(String profileName) {
            File appData = locateAppDataDirectory(Platform.getCurrent());
            Map<String, File> profiles = readProfiles(appData);
            File profileDir = profiles.get(profileName);
            if (profileDir == null)
              return null;
            return new FirefoxProfile(profileDir);
     }
};
FirefoxProfile profile = profileini.getProfile("CustomSeleniumProfile");
//profile.setEnableNativeEvents(false);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
//ffDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Wow, thanks.  The existing ProfilesIni() quit working for some reason, and always returned an anonymous profile directory below /tmp.