# set chrome settings using selenium in C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to change some chrome setting, for example, mark in settings->downloads :"Ask where to save each file before downloading" as "Checked".

The problem, when i'm trying to do this with selenium, it doesn't find me the xPath i provided,
 but when i'm trying this xPath by myself, it's finding the right place (the right checkbox to mark). so my question, is it even possible? and if it is, how??

Thank you!

edit:

one more problem that I noticed, is when after chrome is installed, before the first use, it's doesn't have yet in the chrome settings directory in :C:\Users\%%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\ any default profile. only after the first use it's shown. my question is from where this default profile coming from? i want to configure it before the first use.

Comment: You seem to have multiple issues. Firstly, the profile that will be used will be in the temp folder (%temp%) ...unless you give Selenium a particular profile. Secondly, the setting you desire to change will have no effect at all on what XPath you are running. Thirdly, there is no native setting to do this. Chrome does save it's setting in a JSON file in the User Data folder, I think, you'll have to edit this. Finally, post the HTML you are working with and the XPath expression that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you setup a [browser profiles](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/05_selenium_rc.jsp#specifying-the-firefox-profile)

Comment: tnx, but it's not helping for my use. do you know the answer for mu updated question?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default