# Going through Chrome://settings by Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Java and Selenium to write a test, I use the code below to get into Chrome:setting

```
driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
driverChrome.get("chrome://settings");
```

But when the page is open I can not find any of its web Elements, for example when I try to find "show advanced setting...." by this code

```
driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='advanced-settings-expander']")).click();
```

it throws an error saying that "no such element: Unable to locate element"
I tried to located other elements, but they all failed. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381104/set-chrome-settings-using-selenium-in-c-sharp) post here but it did not help.

Find the code below:

```
    driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
    driverChrome.get("chrome://settings");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    WebElement w = driverChrome.findElement(By
            .xpath("//iframe[@name='settings']"));      
    driverChrome = driverChrome.switchTo().frame(w);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    while (true) {
        try {
            WebElement we = w.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"));             
            if (we.isDisplayed()) {
                we.click();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("=========================");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What settings are you trying to modify? Instead of opening the settings page. Use [`ChromeOptions`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeOptions.html) to modify any settings.

Comment: @JRodDynamite you already helped me with that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33218794/enabling-popup-windows-by-selenium) :) but before  your help I was trying to do it through Chrome:settings and figured out that I can not locate any web elements, so just out of curiosity I want to know why I can not get ay elements from there

Comment: switch to iframe, then try to click.

Comment: That particular element is inside `<iframe name="settings" role="presentation" src="chrome://settings-frame/" data-ready="true"></iframe>`

Comment: @JeffC I used this code:  **WebElement we = driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='settings']//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"));** to get into the iframe and fetch the element bur it failed again. please help.

Comment: You will need to switch to the frame first. A quick google search will show you examples of how to do this.

Comment: @JeffC I added a peace of code to my qoestion, please have a look to it, there I added **riverChrome = driverChrome.switchTo().frame(w);** at the first, please let me know if there is any problem with the code above, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I took your code snippet and cleaned it up a bit. Try this and see if it works. This should be pretty close.

Once you switch to the IFRAME context, you don't need to reference the `IFRAME` as you did with `w.findElement()`.

In general, `Thread.sleep()` is not a good practice. You should prefer to use `WebDriverWait` with `ExpectedConditions`. Check the docs for all the different things you can wait for using `ExpectedConditions`. I used `.elementToBeClickable()` in my code below. This is perfect since you want to click an element. The `.until()` returns the element waited for so you can just append `.click()` on the end of the statement... or you can store the element in a `WebElement` variable and use it elsewhere.

```
driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
driverChrome.get("chrome://settings");
WebElement w = driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='settings']"));
driverChrome = driverChrome.switchTo().frame(w);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverChrome, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']"))).click();

// alternative example... store returned element and then click on a separate line... or use the variable elsewhere, etc.
// WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[text()='Show advanced settings...']")));
// link.click();
```

Comment: Thanks indeed, just a question, why does **w.findElement(bla bla)** throw errors?

Comment: It's not something I've explored but if I were to guess, I would say that the way Selenium implements access to `IFRAME`s is by context... you use `.switchTo()` to navigate into that `IFRAME`'s context so `w.findElement()` doesn't make sense. When you are in the default context, you can't see elements inside `w`. When you are inside `w`'s context, you don't see `w`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to identify Shadow roots to interact with a lot of Chromes native pages including the Settings page.
See this Thread on how to work with them properly:
[How to interact with the elements within #shadow-root (open) while Clearing Browsing Data of Chrome Browser using cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow)