# Use existing Firefox session in Selenium and Perl

Tags: perl, selenium

I have existing Firefox session with appropriate login data to interesting site. Now I want to use it with Selenium and Perl.
I am using this code:

```
my $driver = Selenium::Remote::Driver->new;
$driver->get("http://www.google.com");
$driver->find_element('q','name')->send_keys("Hello WebDriver!");
print $driver->get_title() . "\n";
```

But this code opens new blank session of Firefox.
How can I use my existing session with already set up cookies?

Answer (score 1):

You want to specify a Firefox profile to use.

In Java, it'd be something like this...

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = profile.getProfile("Default"); // might need to switch this around depending on what it actually is named.
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

(credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031253/what-profile-does-selenium-webdriver-use-by-default) for the pseudo-code)

Comment: Unfortunately Perl bindings noes not have ProfilesIni class, either it's analogs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try with this option in perl driver.

```
my $handles = $driver->get_window_handles;
   $driver->switch_to_window($handles->[1]);
   $driver->close;
   $driver->switch_to_window($handles->[0]);
```

I didn't use it, but may be it will help you!

For more information, please refer to this site.
https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Remote::Driver