# How to launch browser as non admin using Webdriver

Tags: selenium, browser, webdriver, non-admin

**Meta -**

OS: WIn 10x 64

Selenium Version: 2.52

**Browser:** 
Firefox 51.0.1
Chrome 52

**Steps to reproduce**

1: Launch Visual studio or Eclipse as admin

2: Create webDriver reference

```
 WebDriver driver;
```

3:Launch FirefoxDriver

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

3: Notice that browser was launched as admin

**Expected Behavior -**

Should be able to launch browser as non admin, when editor (Eclipse/Visual studio) was launched as admin.

**Actual Behavior -**

Browser is launched as admin mode, some Add-Ons do not work on admin mode

Comment: Looks like you are trying to load a specific firefox profile. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12033780 might help