# Why does Selenium open a new Firefox window with my default tab group?

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64654641/selenium-web-driver-and-firefox-is-is-possible-to-create-an-empty-profile-from?noredirect=1#comment114320383_64654641) but it seems to based on broken premises, hopefully the following question is better:

When I use Firefox "manually" I have set it to open a set of 10 tabs whenenever I open a new window `Preferences → Home → Startpage and new windows → Custom addresses` (my translation) but according to the comments to the linked question, Selenium creates a temporary profile with default data unless a specific profile is given as an argument.

**So why does a window opened by Selenium use the default tab set from my personal profile?**

I invoke Selenium, Webdriver and Firefox like this:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

In other words, very basic.

I use the 3.141.59 Web Driver for Java downloaded from here https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: So your question is, why does Selenium use your personal profile, when you have not specified a specific profile for Selenium to use?

Comment: @SnowmanXL Yes, because according to the comments to the linked question, Selenium, as a default, use an anonymous profile. Besides, I have read a lot of questions about people having problems making Selenium use a specific profile, it seems to fallback to an empty/default profile. Am I making a mistake? I would be perfectly happy if Selenium used an empty profile.

Comment: @SnowmanXL E.g., here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/12033780/1802826

Comment: What is the Firefox profile called you use personally, is it perhaps called Default?

Comment: @SnowmanXL 2jyro7k5.default

Answer (score 2):

According to:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5290#issuecomment-396499478

> Selenium will create a new temp profile. It can be either a blank
> profile, or a copy of an existing profile.

That seems to be your case as well.